# Running Node.js as a service on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, node.js, daemon

I'm trying to run a Node.js http server through cygwin as a service, so that it continues to run even once I've logged out (machine still running). The closest I've been able to find is:

```
cygrunsrv -I service_name-p path [-a arguments] 
   [-e VAR=VALUE] [-t auto|manual] [-u user] [-w passwd]
```

used as

```
cygrunsrv -I nodeserver -p /usr/local/bin/node -a ~/server.js
```

but that doesn't seem to run properly... Not sure what I'm doing wrong or if this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh, seems like node-worker was the cause behind the probem. It runs but that part of the pie wasn't working... Oh well. At least I figure it out.